# How to get GitHub user names and emails for a specific team or repository

Tags: python, github-api, github3.py

How would one use Python and the GitHub API to obtain user details (user name, email, location) for a particular team (or repository)? The teams are not public, but I am a member of the team I'm trying to inspect (to prepare a report for the boss).

I've tried using a library like github3py, so far without any luck.

```
import github3
g = github3.login(GH_USERNAME, GH_PASSWORD)
members = g.orgs.team(GH_TEAM)

for u in members
    print u.login
    print u.name
    print u.email
```

Comment: What errors do you get with that code? Your for loop syntax isn't correct

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`PyGithub`](https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub).

**install**

```
pip install PyGithub
```

Get team members like this:

```python
from github import Github
g = Github(GH_USERNAME, GH_PASSWORD)
org = g.get_organization(GH_ORG) //GH_ORG is organization name
teams = org.get_teams()
for t in teams:
    if t.name == GH_TEAM:
        for m in t.get_members():
            print(m.login)
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for using `github3.py`.

What you should be doing is the following:

1. Log into GitHub

   ```
   import github3
   g = github3.login(GH_USERNAME, GH_PASSWORD)
   ```
2. Retrieve your organization

   ```
   organization = g.organization('my-organization-name')
   ```
3. Find your team

   ```
   for team in organization.teams():
       if team.name == 'my-team-name':
           break
   else:
       raise SystemExit('Could not find team named "my-team-name"')
   ```
4. Use the team to enumerate the members

   ```
   for member in team.members():
        print('{}\t{}'.format(member.login, member.name))
   ```

   Note, GitHub's API does not return all the information when enumerating lists of objects (e.g., members of a team). You may need to call `member.refresh()` to retrieve the full User information about a team member.

If you have the team's ID, then step 3 instead could more easily be:

```
team = organization.team(1234)
```